# Modeling a cookie with object composition in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

I'm a new Rubyist and am wondering how I can access the ingredients class from individual cookies? As we all know, cookies are made of different ingredients. How can I specify default ingredients for individual cookies without setting default values? Even if I had default values, how would I update those to reflect the most current "recipe"? Please and thanks!

```
#Cookie Factory   

module CookieFactory
  def self.create(args) 
    cookie_batch = []
    args.each do |cookie|
      cookie_batch << PeanutButter.new if cookie == "peanut butter"
      cookie_batch << ChocholateChip.new if cookie == "chocolate chip"
      cookie_batch << Sugar.new if cookie == "sugar"
    end
    return cookie_batch
  end
end

#Classes/Subclasses 

class Ingredients
  attr_reader 
  def initialize(contents = {})
    # contents = defaults.merge(contents)
    @sugar = contents.fetch(:sugar, "1.5 cups")
    @salt = contents.fetch(:salt, "1 teaspoon")
    @gluten = contents.fetch(:gluten, "0")
    @cinnamon = contents.fetch(:cinnamon, "0.5 teaspoon")
  end
end

class Cookie 
  attr_reader :status, :ingredients

  def initialize(ingredients = {})
    @ingredients = ingredients
    @status = :doughy
    super()
  end

  def bake!
    @status = :baked
  end

end

class PeanutButter < Cookie
  attr_reader :peanut_count
  def initialize
    @peanut_count = 100
    super()
  end 

  def defaults
    {
      :peanut_shells => 5
    }
  end
end

class Sugar < Cookie
  attr_reader :sugar
  def initialize
    @sugar = "1_cup"
    super()
  end
end

class ChocholateChip < Cookie
  attr_reader :choc_chip_count
  def initialize
    @choc_chip_count = 200
    super()
  end
end
```

Comment: For clarification: Say I want to initialize a peanut butter cookie with ingredients of:
0.5 cup butter
1.0 teaspoon peanut oil

how would I add that and update the objects ingredients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Hash#merge` to acheive this behavior:

```
class PeanutButter < Cookie
  attr_reader :peanut_count
  def initialize(ingredients)
    @peanut_count = 100
    super(ingredients.merge(defaults))
  end 

  def defaults
    {
      :peanut_shells => 5
    }
  end
end
```